# Illegal attribute in jsp(sonar violation)

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, sonarqube

In my project I am trying to resolve sonar violation, and I stuck with this one, I have following code

```
<script language="JavaScript"......... > </script>
```

the following attribute is not allowed : language

Can anybody tell me how to resolve this sonar violation ? Can I simply remove this "language"
attribute or should I put type="text/javascript" ?

Comment: yes , simply remove it. by default it is a JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1

The `language` attribute is deprecated.

Use instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript"
```

or

```
script  type="text/JavaScript"
```

or

```
script
```

or

```
if using external js
script src="path to external js"
```

As per standards use second one